# Devolver unicamente array de bytes en propiedad [Buffer]

Tags: json, nodejs, mongoose

Quiero que una propiedad [Buffer] de un esquema me devuelva solo el array de bytes.

Tengo una función que me devuelve un JSON de este estilo:

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "entidadResultante": {
        "imagenByteArray": [
            {
                "type": "Buffer",
                "data": [
                    47,
                    57,
                    ... ESTO ES UN ARRAY DE BYTES
                ]
            }
        ],
        "_id": "6019dc5ba038e84d1421a3f2",
        "codigo": "AAAAAA",
        "descripcion": "aaaaaaaaaaa",
        "nombre": "aaaaaa",
        "precioCosto": 123,
        "precioVenta": 3132213,
        "categoria": {
            "_id": "5fac0163ac7fe522acc202c3",
            "nombre": "Aperitivos"
        },
        "marca": {
            "_id": "6011e7283408972b34fd04a7",
            "nombre": "asd"
        }
    }
}
```

Lo que quiero es que la propiedad **imagenByteArray** devuelva unicamente lo que esta en **data**.
Aclaro que en el esquema de Producto (en Mongoose) la propiedad **imagenByteArray** es así:

```
imagenByteArray: {
        type: [Buffer]
    }
```

Mi código es este:

```
let getProductsById = function(req, res) {
    let id = req.params.id;
    Producto.findById(id, '_id codigo descripcion nombre precioCosto precioVenta categoria marca imagenByteArray')
        .populate('categoria', '_id nombre')
        .populate('marca', '_id nombre')
        .exec((err, producto) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    ok: false,
                    error: 'Error interno en el servidor'
                });
            }
            if (!producto) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    ok: false,
                    error: {
                        message: 'Producto no encontrado'
                    }
                });
            }
            
            res.json({
                ok: true,
                entidadResultante: producto
            });
        });
}
```

Trate de antes de hacer **res.json** probar algunas cosas pero no funcionaron, y al revisar que es lo que me devuelve en la consola la propiedad haciendo esto:

`let data = producto.imagenByteArray[0];`

Me devuelve algo así:

```
 <Buffer 2f 39 6a 2f 34 41 41 51 53 6b 5a 4a 52 67 41 42 41 51 45 41 59 41 42 67 41 41 44 2f 32 77 42 44 41 41 4d 43 41 67 4d 43 41 67 4d 44 41 77 4d 45 41 77 ... 27122 more bytes, _subtype: 0, _markModified: [Function: _markModified], write: [Function: write], copy: [Function: copy], writeUInt8: [Function], writeInt8: [Function], fill: [Function], utf8Write: [Function], asciiWrite: [Function], set: [Function], writeUInt16LE: [Function], writeUInt16BE: [Function], writeUInt32LE: [Function], writeUInt32BE: [Function], writeInt16LE: [Function], writeInt16BE: [Function], writeInt32LE: [Function], writeInt32BE: [Function], writeFloatLE: [Function], writeFloatBE: [Function], writeDoubleLE: [Function], writeDoubleBE: [Function], toObject: [Function], toBSON: [Function], equals: [Function], subtype: [Function], isMongooseBuffer: true, [Symbol(mongoose#Buffer#_path)]: 'imagenByteArray', [Symbol(mongoose#Buffer#_parent)]: { imagenByteArray: [ [Binary] ], _id: 6019dc5ba038e84d1421a3f2, codigo: 'AAAAAA', descripcion: 'aaaaaaaaaaa', nombre: 'aaaaaa', precioCosto: 123, precioVenta: 3132213, categoria: { _id: 5fac0163ac7fe522acc202c3, nombre: 'Aperitivos' }, marca: { _id: 6011e7283408972b34fd04a7, nombre: 'asd' } }>
```

Como puedo devolver solo el array de bytes? Gracias.

Comment: Pero es que ya te está devolviendo el `Array` de `bytes`. ¿Qué quieres enviar al front? El problema no está lo que te devuelve la consulta a la DB, el problema es cómo lo estás manejando o interpretando en el front.

Comment: @MauricioContreras Si es un JSON parseado, serán números. Tendrá que convertirlos a bytes, creo. ¿ Que opinas ?

Comment: Precisamente, a eso quiero llegar, ya se recibe un `Array` de `bytes`. La forma de enviarlo al *front*, es  lo que debe ajustarse. Dependerá de lo que necesite hacer con ese `Array`. Obviamente `res.json` implica conversión a texto y del lado `front` tendría que manejar ese texto para convertirlo en `bytes` nuevamente. Pero sin saber lo que desea hacer con los *bytes*, que ya obtiene en la consulta, es difícil decir cómo proceder. O al menos es lo que pienso IMHO.

Comment: No, me exprese mal, lo que quería es no devolver la propiedad `type` que va en el JSON junto con el array de bytes `data`. Digamos que yo queria unicamente devolver `imagenByteArray: { data: arraydebytes }` y no `imagenByteArray: { type: [Buffer], data: arraydebytes }`